# Почему каждый раз перезаписывается значение в двумерном массиве строк?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Необходима помощь в следующем:

```
char * UserData[4] = { new char[50], new char[50], new char[13], new char[4] };
char *** phoneBook = new char ** [10];

phoneBook[0] = UserData;
gets(UserData[0]);
gets(UserData[1]);
gets(UserData[2]);
gets(UserData[3]);

cout << phoneBook[0][2] << " Test string 1\n\n"; // Вывод стоки, здесь все хорошо.

phoneBook[1] = UserData;
gets(UserData[0]);
gets(UserData[1]);
gets(UserData[2]);
gets(UserData[3]);

// Вывод стоки, здесь всё хорошо.
cout << phoneBook[1][3] << " Test string 2\n\n"; 
// Значение перезаписалось! Почему?
cout << phoneBook[0][2] << " Test string 1\n\n WHY IS IT CHANGING???";
```

1. Проблема в том, что я как бы "перезаписываю" каждый раз значения, которые вводил с клавиатуры.
2. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я имел возможность ввести массив данных 1, потом массив данных 2 и потом сделать их вывод например. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ответы вам уже дали, но вот мне инересно, а вам принципиально не использовать `std::string`, да еще и так извращаться с указателями?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive извините за говнокод, пока учусь, в задании нужно использовать char *, так как std::string, еще будем изучать. Ваш комментарий учту на будущее!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатели phoneBook ссылаются на один и тот же массив.

```
phoneBook[0] = UserData;
phoneBook[1] = UserData;
```

Вам нужна структура
Например:

```
struct phoneBookStruct{
 char UserData0[50];
 char UserData1[50];
 char UserData2[13];
 char UserData3[4];
}
```

Вот её вы можете использовать как массив

```
phoneBookStruct phoneBook[10];

gets(phoneBook[0].UserData0);
gets(phoneBook[0].UserData1);
gets(phoneBook[0].UserData2);
gets(phoneBook[0].UserData3);

cout<<phoneBook[0].UserData0<<" Testing"<<endl;

gets(phoneBook[1].UserData0);
gets(phoneBook[1].UserData1);
gets(phoneBook[1].UserData2);
gets(phoneBook[1].UserData3);

cout<<phoneBook[1].UserData0<<" Testing"<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, вы используйте один и тот же кусок данных – `UserData`:

```
phoneBook[0] = UserData;
phoneBook[1] = UserData;
```

`phoneBook[0]` и `phoneBook[1]` указывают на одни и те же данные

И для `c++` рекомендуется использовать `std::string`, а не `char *`